# Why is the energy levels in hydrogen independent of the quantum numbers l and ml?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I've been looking for an answer for this for quite a bit but I'm still quite confused. On the independence from ml, I think that it originates from the symmetry of the molecule. However, the independence from l, is what confuses me. Others have mentioned that it is due to the fact that the potential energy is purely Coulombic and related to the 1/r aspect. However, my textbook shows that the effective potential energy (related to the radial wavefunction) actually depends on two things: the Coulomb potential energy and the centrifugal force from angular momentum. The latter has the l quantum number, so when l = 0, the effective potential energy is purely coulombic. However, when l is not 0, the effective potential isn't purely Coulombic, which contradicts my earlier statement. So I'm a bit confused on whether the potential energy is purely coulombic/not, or if we are referring to different potential energies?

Comment: Your thinking is correct. As it happens there exists a cunning ploy to confuse us all :) In a Coulomb potential there is an *accidental* degeneracy which means that the energy does not depend on $l$, The degeneracy wrt the magnetic quantum number $m_l$ depends on symmetry, i.e. an atoms properties are independent of orientation in space ( in the absence of external fields)